# How do I dial a Twilio SIP endpoint

Tags: twilio, sip, plivo

So far, Twilio endpoints are seeming more like middle points, since all my attempts to dial them have failed.

I have a Twilio SIP endpoint created with URI `testuri123.sip.twilio.com`. I am dialing this URI from arbitrary IPs, so instead of creating an IP whitelist, I did credentials. I created a username/password combination, and am still unable to dial any SIP addresses at that URI.

For example, I use getonsip.com to test SIP connections, and I'm not able to get my XML endpoint to be requested. I do see a proxy authentication go by in the console, so that's new. I don't  know how to configure that in a regular SIP dial address.

For a given username, I expect the URI for dialing to be `username@testuri123.sip.twilio.com`, but this always fails. For what it's worth, I follow very similar steps on a competitor of Twilio, and things work fine. On Plivo, I create a SIP endpoint, set a username/password, and I'm able to ring that endpoint without any fuss, using the format above.